# c# run commands through cmd

Tags: c#, .net, apache, cmd

I need to execute two commands on the cmd. Despite my research I have not found a workable solution to my problem. First I need to cd to directory and then run an exe in that directory.

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Blacksmith\bin\apache\bin";
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = @" \c httpd.exe";

    // Redirects the standard input so that commands can be sent to the shell.
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOutputDataHandler;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessErrorDataHandler;

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

I'm trying to execute httpd.exe through cmd.exe to stop apache from being run as a windows service.

Comment: Are you trying to get a command prompt with httpd.exe or are you simply trying to execute httpd.exe?

Comment: I'm simply trying to execute httpd.exe through cmd.exe to stop apache from being windows service.

Comment: Yeah, why don't you start `httpd.exe` directly?

Comment: Becuase that runs apache as a service

Comment: You can't use shell and redirects together.

Comment: Does running httpd.exe directly start it as a daemon and return back to your program immediately? It won't be a windows service unless you install it as one.

Comment: Why are you redirecting Input when you are not writing to it?

Comment: @GabrielGraves It depends on the httpd.exe. How does it behave when you run int from command line?

Comment: When you say "I'm trying to execute httpd.exe through cmd.exe to stop apache from being run as a windows service." what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Blacksmith\bin\apache\bin\httpd.exe";

    // Redirects the standard input so that commands can be sent to the shell.
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOutputDataHandler;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessErrorDataHandler;

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Notice OPs `\c` command line argument, wont that be necessary?

Comment: @GabrielGraves, thanks `cmd.exe \c httpd.exe` is a valid command.

Comment: this does not work as it fails witch message httpd does not exists or is not a bla bla command.

Comment: Yes that path is and has been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Blacksmith\bin\apache\bin";
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "httpd.exe";

    // Redirects the standard input so that commands can be sent to the shell.
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOutputDataHandler;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessErrorDataHandler;

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might try /c instead of \c